# How does MVVM architecture work in an android project that uses a REST API?

Tags: android, rest, mvvm, clean-architecture

I'm working on an application that accesses its' data through a REST API app. All is going well until I get to the part where I need to change the data and refresh it in my Screens.

My process is this:
-user does something on screen
-I notify my viewmodel from the composable and the viewmodel calls the usecase that will update the data
-this is the point where the data is updated in the backend database, but it's not in my viewmodel

I'm wondering, what is a good MVVM practice here?
Do I retrieve the data again with a GET request? It seems exessive to make so many API calls.
Do I use the API response to update the state of my viewModel? For example, if I have a list on screen, and I create a new listitem, I add the response object to my list that the viewmodel observes?

What is the elegant way to refresh data?

Comment: `what is a good MVVM practice here?` mvvm is an architecture, it's not going to give you an answer on how to cache your data or when you should be fetching from the api again. `It seems exessive to make so many API calls.` how would we know ? if it doesn't make sense in your case to do that, then cache it, in memory, room db, files, etc. but perhaps it makes sense to get the latest data often ? again, we can't make these decisions and mvvm has very little to do with this, as you'd have had this question with any other architecture as well, right ?

Answer (score 0):

MVVM is a Frontend architecture that gives a way to handle view and data communication by putting a ViewModel between them and using the binding/command as principals tools.
I agreed that MVVM cannot gives responses to all coding problems.

But from an architecture point of view what I recommend is to separate the result of your API from any other classes/structures. Introduce what we call DTO objects as parameter/responses of the API calls.

After calling the API convert these DTO to your view models when needed.

The second point about to cache or not to cache API result, it up to you to measure the application performance, usage. My only advise is to cache when need to cache :)

Thanks.